# Server Sent Events on an API

Tags: node.js, api, express, server-sent-events

I have currently setup an endpoint for Server Sent Events on my Express API, when i call the endpoint from cmd with `curl -H Accept:text/event-stream http://localhost:3000/v1/devices`,  i get the stream, but when I call the endpoint from my Vue app with `new EventSource('http://localhost:3000/v1/devices')` but it just keeps loading without streaming any data. Is there anything I am to do that I am currently not doing?

NOTE: When i listen for the `open` event, i get a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it works as it should. It was one of the middlewares i setup that was blocking it. Any information on why that is so would be welcome.